# Как сгенерировать Claim заголовок Instagram

Tags: java, c#, python, instagram

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Есть заголовок X-IG-WWW-Claim он важный, т.к отвечает без него запрос получается "bad" - 400.
Искал и на зарубежных форумах и на наших, так ничего дельного и не нашел, если есть кто знает как его сгенерировать, жду вас в комментариях)
ЯП не важен, важен сам алгоритм генерации, либо где его можно достать(заголовок)?

https://89.219.33.13/amix/instagram-private-api/commit/a1f3f156f86cf83c0fb67e1e7a794f01d9505824?view=parallel

Из этой ссылки можно узать, что в ответе какого-то запроса есть данный заголовок

Comment: У вас написано `instagram-api`, но API вы не используете. Вероятно, этот ключ генерируется динамически, дабы как то ограничить автоматическую авторизацию.

Comment: @ГеннадийП Динамически - т.е каждый раз? Если да, то это понятно, мне и нужна сам алгоритм генерации, либо мб его можно где-то достать, например в html в какой-то ссылке прячут, вдруг

Comment: Ну так смотрите в браузере логи сети и смотрите какой скрипт отправляет первый запрос с таким заголовком, затем все предыдущие запросы и ответы на них. Из воздуха заголовки не берутся. Сайт - это приложение, с открытым, можно сказать кодом, и отладчик есть - инструменты разработчика в браузере. Задача может быть творческая, но выполнимая.

Comment: @aepot В том то и дело, было бы это так просто. Там запрос идет, самый первый POST запрос, в его теле уже сгенерированный этот токен, все, он генерируется самим сайтом, и заносится в пост запрос, далее остальным передается

Comment: @aepot я бы мог  попытаться в js полазить сайта, но как найти нужный js

Comment: `в его теле уже сгенерированный этот токен` - это значит, что у вас не чистая сессия, вы ловите то, что уже сохранено у вас в браузере. Либо, это значение в HTML странице сайта. Попробуйте очистить все Cookie (а лучше вовсе в режиме инкогнито запуститесь) и в Fiddler отлавливайте все запросы, а как дойдете до нужного, то жмите `Ctrl+F` и ищите по его значению, предварительно поставив чекбокс на расшифровке ответа. Я уверен, вы найдете источник данного значение.

Comment: Зачем fiddler, если есть девтулз firefox и chrome? Первый для отладки кода хорошо, а не браузера.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Спасибо, нашел. Я думал, что он сайтом генерируется, и выдается. Был такой опыт с 1 сайтом, где генерировлся токен в js, я думал тут так же

Comment: @vazgen5678 Ну тогда ответом напишите результат, если это конечно решило вашу проблему.

Comment: @aepot Тут он просто на скрине, по этой причине и упомянул. А так, не совсем соглашусь, ибо если идет отлов кучи запросов, хочется знать полностью что делает этот сайт, то `Fiddler` самое то, а браузерные утилиты, они предназначены для отлова нескольких простых запросов. Но тут дело вкуса, да.

Answer (score 1):

`X-IG-WWW-Claim` идет по умолчанию равным 0, после авторизации, или после отправки кода подтверждения приходит заголовок `x-ig-set-www-claim` в котором есть уже это значение